# Trigger outbound message/API Endpoint on record delete

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage, workflowrule

On the `Event` table I have a workflow rule that sends an outbound message that notifies my external API when a record is created and updated.

1) Is it possible to have the workflow send an outbound message to my external API **when a record is deleted**?

2) If not, what is the simplest way to accomplish this? My application needs a few select fields from the record.

Edit: apparently 1) is not possible, however I still need the simplest way to do this.

Comment: The answer in that question suggests it's not possible to trigger workflow rules on delete like I suspected, but I'd still like to know the simplest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Workflow or Process Builder don't trigger on Delete DML (yet) - see [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DlPBAA0) and vote it up then ...

**Option 1**

- Write an AfterDelete Trigger on the object that uses a future or queueable apex class to make the callout
- The async class can do the callout synchronously and manage the response directly

**Option 2**

- Write an AfterDelete Trigger on the `Event` object that creates a new "proxy" `Event` that contains the data of the deleted event.
- Add logic to your workflow rule to recognize this proxy *deleted-Event-masquerading-as-a-new-Event* and make the outbound message
- In some recurring job, delete these proxy `Event`s after their callouts are done.

Comment: Is it not possible to trigger an outbound message with an apex trigger? If i create an outbound message that sends what I need to my API endpoint, can I write a very simple trigger than sends it out?

Comment: apex trigger can't do callouts; have to delegate to an async class

Comment: I see. So I gather apex coding is my only option here, no other built in salesforce way to do this

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Others may give you a better answer.  Don't forget to vote up the Idea.  You can see it is quite popular.

Comment: It's honestly ridiculous that salesforce doesn't support this natively.